# printing the below pattern using just one loop

Tags: c++, loops

ive got the below code to print a pattern (attached below). However i'd like to just use one loop

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=n-i;j++){
            if(j%2!=0){
                cout<<"_";
            }else{
                cout<<".";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=n-i;j++){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            if(j%2==0){
                cout<<".";
            }else{
                cout<<"_";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

when n = 5, heres the output.

```
*_._.
**_._
***_.
****_
*****
****_
***_.
**_._
*_._.
```

how do i just make this into one single loop

Comment: What is your actual assignment or exercise? What are its actual requirements and limitations? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste it (as text) into the question. I'm asking because the requirement to do it in only one loop just isn't possible.

Comment: You can delegate off the inner loops to various C++ standard library functions, but they're always going to be there somewhere.

Comment: The code is readable and sensible. I do not see why I should show you how to do it in one loop. (I.e. I think it is possible, just should not be done. @Someprogrammerdude ) Please explain the need. I ask because I think we are looking at a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: im expecting bonus marks upon just implementing the pattern into one single loop. @Someprogrammerdude. im talking about the main loop. just instead of two main loops, i need one.

Comment: ah im actually told ill be given bonus marks upon implementing a single loop. and I did try tagging the question as homework but was unable to do so.

Comment: So nested loops inside a single "main" loop? Then that makes more sense.

Comment: yeah thats what im looking for, sorry i couldnt phrase myself correctly. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I misread, or actually missed completly, the clarification. Pity. I almost got the single loop version done by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see how it does what you want to understand the step you did not find on your own:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n*2-1; i++) {
        if (i <= n)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                cout << "*";
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
                if (j % 2 != 0) {
                    cout << "_";
                }
                else {
                    cout << ".";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n*2 - i; j++) {
                cout << "*";
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= i-n; j++) {
                if (j % 2 == 0) {
                    cout << ".";
                }
                else {
                    cout << "_";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consistent indentation (and a fix of markup) would make more obvious that you are using a single main `for`. As it is, it looks like a `for` followed by an `if`. Also, I recommend to use an `else` instead of that  `if`.

Comment: definitely what i was looking for. a minor change in indentation and using ```else``` instead as suggested by @Yunnosch made it even better. thanks

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm still new to posting here and somehow, the editor does not want to indent it the way it shows in my editor here. Sure, else makes it more readable as well.

Comment: I assume that you have tabulators which are lost here. Just indent here with blanks. Apart from that check https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to just use one loop.

I'll take it literally and show a starting point for a possible solution.

```C++
// Let's start by figuring out some dimensions.
int n;
std::cin >> n;                  
int height = 2 * n - 1;
int area = n * height;

// Now we'll print the "rectangle", one piece at a time.
for (int i = 0; i < area; ++i)
{ //            ^^^^^^^^
  // Extract the coordinates of the char to be printed.
  int x = i % n;
  int y = i / n;
  
  // Assign a symbol, based on such coordinates.
  if ( x <= y  and  x <= height - y - 1 )
  { // ^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    Those are the diagonals.  
    std::cout << '*'; // This prints correctly the triangle on the left...
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << '_'; // <---  But of course, something else should done here. 
  }
  
  // End of row.
  if ( x == n - 1 )
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the pattern, then you can see a sort of "triangles". And this already gives a hint for the solution. Use a triangle function.

Please read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function).

Then you will notice that always the "aboslute"-function, in C++ `std::abs`, is involved.

But first of all, it is easily visible that the number rows to print is always the width of a triangle * 2.

And the number of charcters in the pattern, can be calculated by applying the triangle function. Example for width 5:

```
     Number of stars        number of dashdot
Row  width-abs(row-width)   abs(row-width)

 1             1                  4 
 2             2                  3
 3             3                  2
 4             4                  1
 5             5                  0
 6             4                  1
 7             3                  2 
 8             2                  3
 9             1                  4
```

And this can be implemented easily now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std::string_literals;

int main() {
    // Get the max width of the pattern and perform a short input validation
    int maxWidth{};
    if ((std::cin >> maxWidth) and (maxWidth > 0)) {

        // The number of rows for the pattern is dependent on the width. It is a simple relation
        const int numberOfRows = 2 * maxWidth;

        // Show all rows
        for (int row = 1; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {

            // Use triangle formular to create star pattern
            std::string starPattern(maxWidth - std::abs(row - maxWidth), '*');

            // Create dashDot pattern
            std::string ddp(std::abs(row - maxWidth), '\0');
            std::generate(ddp.begin(), ddp.end(), [i = 0]() mutable { return i++ % 2 ? '.' : '_'; });

            // Show output
            std::cout << (starPattern+ddp) << '\n';
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "\n*** Error: Invalid input\n\n";
}
```

Of course you can also create the whole pattern wit `std::generate`.

Maybe it is too complex for now.

And less understandable.

See:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Get the max width of the pattern and perform a short input validation
    if (int width{}; (std::cin >> width) and (width > 0)) {

        std::vector<std::string> row(2 * width - 1);

        std::for_each(row.begin(), row.end(), [&, r = 1](std::string& s) mutable {
        s = std::string(width - std::abs(r - width), '*');
        std::string ddp(std::abs(r++ - width),'\0');
        std::generate(ddp.begin(), ddp.end(), [&, i = 0]()  mutable{ return i++ % 2 ? '.' : '_'; });
        s += ddp; std::cout << s << '\n'; });
    }
    else std::cout << "\n*** Error: Invalid input\n\n";
}
```